# Highlight manpages syntax?

Tags: manpage

Is there a way to "colorize" manpages output?
I mean - the output of for example:

```
man command_name
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use the following shell function to view manpages in Vim, which provides nice syntax highlighing:

```
man() {
  /usr/bin/man $* | \
    col -b | \
    vim -R -c 'set ft=man nomod nolist' -
}
```

Comment: and finally I won't be pressing _j_ by mistake all the time

Comment: Well, `j` works fine in less as well :)

Comment: But you should change `$*` to `"$@"` to avoid potential problems with white space. Otherwise, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I suggest a little modification, to get more close to `less` style: substitute `vim` with `/usr/share/vim/vim72/macros/less.sh`.

Comment: @enzotib as versions change, use `/usr/share/vim/vim*/macros/less.sh` will be version proof, as of 2020

Answer (score 5):

add `export PAGER=most` to **.bashrc**

Comment: this is great, but is there a way to make it work for HELP and INFO commands ?

Comment: It's `export PAGER="most"` (with quotation marks), and you'll need to install it first using `apt-get install most` (cf. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-color-man-pages-configuration/).

Answer (score 4):

aha. adding this to ~/.bashrc does the trick. It's not perfect though. but hey:

```
# Less Colors for Man Pages 
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m'       # begin blinking 
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;38;5;74m'  # begin bold 
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'           # end mode 
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'           # end standout-mode 
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[38;5;246m'    # begin standout-mode - info box 
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'           # end underline 
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[04;38;5;146m' # begin underline
```

Comment: Why man pages in virtual terminal have a minimum of color (cyan for bold), and in graphic terminal are black and white?

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be in the terminal?

Else you can use:
System->Help->System Documentation
and on the left of the window that comes up click "Manual Pages" (found this tip [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-310345.html))

Or you can use Konqueror, which shows the man pages like this:
[image: Man page in Konqueror]

Comment: wow. didn't know one can do that.

Comment: Does any other browser support this?

Answer (score 3):

The answer [Adam Byrtek](https://askubuntu.com/a/35730/772375) seems to limit lines to 80 characters and doesn't reflow text when you resize your terminal.

You can fix this by setting `MANPAGER` instead. You can also set `PAGER` like [daithib8](https://askubuntu.com/a/44877/772375) does but that is more general. `MANPAGER` overrides `PAGER` for the `man` command.

From [this](https://zameermanji.com/blog/2012/12/30/using-vim-as-manpager/)

```
export MANPAGER="col -b | vim -c 'set ft=man ts=8 nomod nolist nonu' -c 'nnoremap i <nop>' -"
```

He has some pretty good extra options such as setting `ts` (tabstop), `nonu` (nonumber), and unmapping `i` (insert). So I will merge the two solutions. Also made some improvements like using the `command` command and expanding arguments with `"$@"`

As a function:

```
man() {
  MANPAGER="col -b | vim -R -c 'set ft=man ts=8 nomod nolist nonu' -c 'nnoremap i <nop>' -" command man "$@"
}
```

**EDIT:** scroll down to my **UPDATE** to see benefits of using this messy form and a cleaner way to write the function with some extra vim mappings.

---

But doing all this is a really big mess. The following solutions require installation but they are cleaner solutions.

These solutions don't have the `Vim: Reading from stdin...` that the above solution has.

I recommend [daithib8](https://askubuntu.com/a/44877/772375)'s answer except to use `MANPAGER` instead of `PAGER` since this question is just about manpages. And I would also add it to my `.bash_profile` or `.profile` so it doesn't get exported on each invocation of `bash`. You will have to install `most` though.

```
# In .profile or .bash_profile
MANPAGER='most'
```

`most` doesn't have `hjkl` movement like in `vim` and `less`, but it is the fastest.

Also, [`vimpager`](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager#-u-vimrc) is pretty good. I like using it for huge manpages such as `man bash`. You get all the cool things from vim such as line numbers `number`, highlighted search `hlsearch`, and all your vim plugins.

If you have [`YouCompleteMe`](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) installed `vimpager` also doesn't show this message:

```
The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ':YcmRestartServer'). Unexpected exit code 1. Type ':YcmToggleLogs ycmd_54959_stderr_UvwUrj.log' to check the logs.
```

Not sure why, but it's nice not to see that.

```
# In .profile or .bash_profile
export MANPAGER='vimpager'
```

Startup can be a bit slower than `most` because `vimpager` sources your `.vimrc`, which can be a good thing, if you want to use your vim plugins. To disable `.vimrc` sourcing:

```
# In .profile or .bash_profile
export MANPAGER='vimpager -u NONE'
```

---

You can also do a hybrid approach with functions:

```
# Use 'command man' instead of 'man' if you have overridden
# 'man' with a function, like how I did in the "messy" solutions above.

manmost() {
    MANPAGER='most' man "$@"
}

manvim() {
    MANPAGER='vimpager -u NONE' man "$@"
}

manvimrc() {
    MANPAGER='vimpager' man "$@"
}
```

So now, `export MANPAGER` will set your default `MANPAGER` in your `.bash_profile` or `.profile`, but you can use any one of these functions to quickly use another `MANPAGER`.

---

**UPDATE**

Actually, vimpager is a little different than actual vim. For example, in normal mode, `w` is mapped to `b` and `b` is mapped to `& <C-B><SNR>1_L`. But this is how other pagers are - less doesn't have a cursor.

If you would like to use actual vim, with a messy solution, I found [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/how-can-i-suppress-the-reading-from-stdin-message-from-within-vim). It suppresses the `Vim: Reading from stdin...` with a hack. Still has the YouCompleteMe message though. You can probably set another `-c` command to do turn off YouCompleteMe. But I'll just ignore that message.

```
manrealvim() {
  MANPAGER='bash -c "vim -MRn -c \"set ft=man nomod nolist nospell nonu\" -c \"nm q :qa!<CR>\" -c \"nm <end> G\" -c \"nm <home> gg\"</dev/tty <(col -b)"' man "$@"
}
```

In newer [vim versions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11722), you can avoid this hack with `--not-a-term`:

I cleaned up the function with newline escapes because this is the version I am using.

```
manvim() {
  MANPAGER='col -b | '\
'vim -MR -c "set ft=man ts=8 nomod nolist nospell nonu" '\
'-c "set colorcolumn= hlsearch incsearch" '\
'-c "nun <buffer> q" '\
'-c "nn q :qa!<CR>" '\
'-c "nn <end> G" '\
'-c "nn <home> gg" '\
'- --not-a-term' man "$@"
}
```

Or you can just use [neovim > v0.2.2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14236):

```
# not sure why but the -M flag breaks it but it's not required
# Seems like nvim already sets -M when ft=man
mannvim() {
  MANPAGER='col -b | '\
'nvim -R -c "set ft=man ts=8 nomod nolist nospell nonu" '\
'-c "nun <buffer> q" '\
'-c "nn q :qa!<CR>" '\
'-c "nn <end> G" '\
'-c "nn <home> gg" '\
'-' man "$@"
}
```

You might want to look through the vim options passed to customize. I looked through them from all those posts I listed and chose the ones I liked. Or you can just copy me.

You could also parse `vim --version` to determine whether to use the hack or `--not-a-term`. I won't do that here.

---

**MY CURRENT METHOD**

If you would like to set this vim method as your default `MANPAGER`, do the following:

1. Add these executable scripts in your path:

   There are two scripts because the first is for general paging (replacement for less), while the second is for manpaging (has manpage syntax highlighting.

   ```
   # Put this in ~/bin/vimrealpager
   # I call it vimrealpager to avoid name clashes with vimpager mentioned above
   # Make sure ~/bin/ is in your path

   # ***SCRIPT START***

   #!/usr/bin/env sh

   col -b |
   vim -MR -c 'set nomod nolist nospell nonu' \
   -c 'set colorcolumn= hlsearch incsearch' \
   -c 'nn q :qa!<CR>' \
   -c 'nn <end> G' \
   -c 'nn <home> gg' \
   "$@" \
   --not-a-term \
   -
   ```

   ```
   # Put this in ~/bin/vimrealmanpager
   # ***SCRIPT START***

   #!/usr/bin/env sh

   vimrealpager -c 'set ft=man' \
   -c 'nun <buffer> q'
   ```
2. In your ~/.profile:

   ```
   export MANPAGER='vimrealmanpager'
   ```

You could also do `export -f` on the functions I showed earlier, but it works in bash but not POSIX shell, so you would have to put it in .bash_profile instead of .profile.

A similar thing can be done for `nvim` but I'm not gonna add it here unless requested.